# Python return next words/number

Tags: python

```
s= '''number 100-200-300
    number 200-400-500
    number 200-500-300
    numb   undefined
    gone  300-400-500
    going 400-500-300

    stop
    This is some kind of number but doesn't print
    number 300-400-500
    number 200-100-400
'''
sl = s.split()

def nextword(target, source):
    for i, w in enumerate(source):
        if w == target:
            return (source[i+1])
```

Printing returns

```
print nextword('number', sl)    
'100-200-300'
```

However, I want to return all the numbers instead of just returning first number.

print nextword('num'/'gone'/'going', sl) ?

```
100-200-300
200-400-500
200-500-300
300-400-500
400-500-300
undefined
stop
300-400-500
200-100-400
```

Comment: Hard to tell if there is more logic that just slicing the resultant `split()` or does it have to start `'number'` (you print `undefined` and that starts with `numb`??). And you are probably looking for `yield` rather than `return` in your function (look up `generators`)

Comment: Will you please stop editing your question, which fundamentally changes the answers. Just ask new questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a list of numbers, and then do as you will with them:

```
def nextword(target, source):
    words = []
    for i, w in enumerate(source):
        if w == target:
            words.append(source[i+1])
    return words
```

Then, now that you have a list, to print the words one per line:

```
print '\n'.join(nextword('number', sl))
```

To do partial matching, you can use `in`:

```
def nextword(target, source):
    words = []
    for i, w in enumerate(source):
        if target in w:
            words.append(source[i+1])
    return words
```

Following AChampion's suggestion, it would be better to use `yield`:

```
def nextword(target, source):
    for i, w in enumerate(source):
        if target in w:
            yield source[i+1]
```

To print `stop` no matter what the `target` was:

```
def nextword(target, source):
    for i, w in enumerate(source):
        if w == 'stop':
            yield w
        elif target in w:
            yield source[i+1]
```

To match multiple words, use a list for `target`, with `any` to match any of them:

```
def nextword(target, source):
    words = []
    for i, w in enumerate(source):
        if any(t in w for t in target):
            yield source[i+1]

print ('\n'.join(nextword(['num', 'go'], sl)))
```

Comment: What about undefined? Also, I want to be able to call print ('num', sl)

Comment: Any reason not to use a generator and just `yield` the word vs assembling an array and returning it... the caller can do what they want with the results (works for the `join() without ever creating an intermediate list.

Comment: @AChampion none at all, I just forgot about `yield`.

Comment: @muru If I add something like stop, how to print stop as well? Added in the Q.

Comment: @user5977290 That's hard to tell. How exactly does `stop` fit into the picture? Should it be printed no matter what target word was specified?

Comment: @user5977290 check for stop condition and `break`

Comment: @AChampion apparently they want to print `stop` as well, going from the updated question.

Comment: @muru right, stop should be printed regardless of the target and source.

Comment: @muru if gone 200-100-400 is listed in the s  - for something like this, is there way to partially pick out gone and number together?

Comment: @user5977290 for that maybe you could  pass a list of target words, and check all of them `for t in target: if w in t: ...` or, use regular expressions.

Comment: @muru I've added in Q. Can you provide examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you need your function to work then what you need is a generator:

```
def nextword(target, source):
    for i, w in enumerate(source):
        if w == target:
            yield source[i+1]
```

But python also has generator expressions, and this would do the same as above:

```
print '\n'.join(s1[i+1] for i, w in enumerate(s1) if w == 'number')
```

But you could also do:

```
s1 = iter(s.split())
print '\n'.join(x for w, x in zip(s1, s1) if w == 'number')
```

** Update: Based on OP edits. It is easier to split on `'\n'` then split the line:

```
def nextword(target, source):
    for s in source:
        s1 = s.split()
        if not s1:   # Blank lines
            continue
        if any(s1[0].startswith(t) for t in target):
            yield s1[1]
        if s1[0] == 'stop':
            yield 'stop'

print('\n'.join(nextword(['numb', 'go'], s.split('\n'))))
```

Output:

```
100-200-300
200-400-500
200-500-300
undefined
300-400-500
400-500-300
stop
300-400-500
200-100-400
```

Comment: Did you intend to shift the second `s1` in that last snippet? `zip(s1, s1[1:])`, perhaps?

Comment: No, `s1` is an iterator in the last example and `zip` calls `next` so this will advance as expected. But I do need to `join` it so fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
print([line.split()[-1] for line in s.splitlines()])
```

Prints `['100-200-300', '200-400-500', '200-500-300', 'undefined']`.

Note that you may additionally apply the check on each line, for instance:

```
[line.split()[-1] for line in s.splitlines() if "numb" in line]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall()`:

```
import re
print re.findall('\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}|undefined', s)
```

Comment: How about `undefined`?

Comment: @alecxe I added it, but now it's probably too hacky.